# JavaFX как сделать закругленный объект?

Tags: java, javafx

Хочу сделать такой объект, и поставить на него размытие по Гауссу

[image: Приблизительно, что нужно]

Comment: Да вроде даем параметры по [документации](http://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/FX/2.0.3/docs/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html)  и всё вроде  и тут показывается наглядно http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html

Comment: спасибо, все получилось!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы скруглить углы у прямоугольника, достаточно просто лишь вызвать соответствующие методы класса.

Если следовать [документации](http://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/FX/2.0.3/docs/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html), можно увидеть, что за скругление отвечают параметры:

`arcWidth` - определяет горизонтальный диаметр дуги в четырех углах прямоугольника 
`arcHeight` - определяет вертикальный диаметр дуги в четырех углах прямоугольника.

Их можно установить через `setArcWidth` и `setArcHeight` соответственно.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(110, 110, 200, 200);
rect.setArcWidth(20);
rect.setArcHeight(20);
rect.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
rect.setStrokeWidth(10);
```

Если используется `Canvas`, то при рисовании можно указать эти параметры сразу в конструкторе 5-ым и 6-ым параметрами:

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setFill(Color.RED);    
gc.fillRoundRect(50, 50, 100, 100, 30, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно использовать [`css`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) : `-fx-border-radius` и `-fx-border-insets`